# Do I have to eject if I want to use SASS with create react app?

Tags: reactjs, sass, create-react-app

If I want to use Sass for my CSS, do I have to eject my create-react-app project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes...No... If you want to use SASS you should consider using webpack to bundle your source. This is merely an opinion.

But if you don't want too, here is a link:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-a-css-preprocessor-sass-less-etc